Power Query: Multiple Criteria Filtering with Logical Operators
I have the following table in power query:

I'm trying to return the latest files for BOTH words "RAM" and "SoCal".  In this case, the return files would be:
RR RAM 2024-07-08.xlsx
RR SoCal 2024-08-05.xlsx
How would I write a function to do this?
I tried:
= Table.SelectRows(GetDateFromFileName, let latest = List.Max(GetDateFromFileName[Text Between Delimiters]) in each [Text Between Delimiters] = latest and (Text.Contains([Name], "RAM") or Text.Contains([Name], "SoCal")))

But it did not work.
Thank you

Can you paste the image as copiable text. Is this Excel or PowerBI?

@davidebacci it's PowerQuery in Excel
Binary RR RAM 2024-07-05.xlsx 7/5/2024
Binary RR RAM 2024-07-08.xlsx 7/8/2024
Binary RR SoCal 2024-07-01.xlsx 7/1/2024
Binary RR SoCal 2024-07-08.xlsx 7/8/2024
Binary RR SoCal 2024-08-05.xlsx 8/5/2024

Update your question with the sample data in text format

Try:

Add a custom conditional column depending if Name contains the string you want.
Sort on the date column Text Between Delimiters DESCENDING
Buffer the table to maintain the sort order.
Remove duplicates on the conditional column

Similar to:
let
    ...
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(GetDateFromFileName, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Name], "RAM") then "RAM" else if Text.Contains([Name], "SoCal") then "SoCal" else "ignore"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"Text Between Delimiters", Order.Descending}}),
    TableBuffer = Table.Buffer(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(TableBuffer, {"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"



Follow-up to the ask in the comments about doing similar but keeping the top 3 of each category:

GroupBy on the category column while keeping all Rows.
Transform the nested table by sorting it then taking the Top 3 rows.
Expand the nested table

Example:
let
  ...,
  #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(GetDateFromFileName, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Name], "RAM") then "RAM" else if Text.Contains([Name], "SoCal") then "SoCal" else "ignore"),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column", {"Custom"}, {{"Rows", each _, type nullable table[Content = nullable text, Name = nullable text, #"Text Between Delimiters" = nullable Int64.Type, Custom = any]}}),
  #"Sort and Take" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped rows", {"Rows", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_, {{"Text Between Delimiters", Order.Descending}}), 3) }),
  #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Sort and Take", "Rows", {"Content", "Name", "Text Between Delimiters"}, {"Content", "Name", "Text Between Delimiters"})
in
  #"Expanded Rows"


Brilliant. Thanks so much. So basically you sort by date then remove duplicates by the custom column. Is this correct?  What exactly does Table.Buffer do? I ready that its necessary to use that to make Table.Distinct act predictably, but is that the only reason?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-buffer

Yes that's correct, remove duplicates keeps the first and removes the others hence order descending. See Remove Duplicates and Keep the Last Record with Power Query for why Table.Buffer is needed.

Thanks--One more question. What if you wanted to keep the top 3 files of each RAM or SoCal, but there could be different combination of dates of each category?

Have a look at the Follow-up bottom half of the updated answer above - see if that works for you.

Sam, am I able to use the UI to do the grouping? I'm having trouble following which options you're using for the grouping and what exactly is going on. Would you be able to provide more details?  Thank you again.

Sure, the grouping is done like so: https://i.sstatic.net/tLqkxjyf.png. This creates a nested table, the "Sort and Take" step then transforms this nested table.
